# AttributeError with DateAxisItem.py

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I'm new in python and i'm trying to use pyqtgraph to plot time series. 
I found [this](https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph/commit/eda54fe9a5e82cad78e329eee1b27640334e511b) to help me but:

```
pg.DateAxisItem('left', pen=None, linkView=None, parent=None, maxTickLength=-1, showValues=True).tickStrings(_dateTS,1, 1)
```

gives me an ettribute error: (_dateTS is a list of timestamp)

```
    154         tick_specs = self.zoom_level.tick_specs
    155         tick_spec = next((s for s in tick_specs if s.spacing == spacing), None)
--> 156         dates = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(v - self.utc_offset) for v in values]
    157         format_strings = []
    158         for x in dates:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'utcfromtimestamp'
```

This error occurs in DateAxisItem.py

I've read some threads saying that it  be might be due to some import error.
Here's the way i import module

```
import fileinput
import glob
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore
import time
import datetime
```

As i said i'm starting with python and I can't see where i'am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `from datetime import datetime`

Or:

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(v - self.utc_offset)
```

As the error suggests `datetime` is the actual module .
`

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(...)

Ipython might be helpful :)

Comment: how is this different from my answer?

Comment: Four minutes is not the same time

Comment: I'am not gonna argue. When I posted, there was no other answers present. I think this is big solution and everything is not done just in realtime, so I have no notifications and no information. Just look for time of last comment-answer and consider that I answered in the same minute that I received notification, but there are exacly 4 minutes lag. EOT.